# Cordova plugin facebook4, how to use it?

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, cordova-plugins, quasar-framework

I am integrating the Facebook login to my hybrid app and for this I have used [cordova-plugin-facebook4](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-facebook4).

## run in cmd

```
$cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-facebook4 --save --variable APP_ID="1854483668193025" --variable APP_NAME="Lojas"
```

## config.xml

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-facebook4" spec="^2.2.0">
        <variable name="APP_ID" value="1854483668193025" />
        <variable name="APP_NAME" value="Lojas" />
</plugin>
```

## run cordova browser

```
$cordova run browser
```

## error

> FB.login() called before FB.init().

## console

[image]

## code

```
login () {
  window.facebookConnectPlugin.login(['email, public_profile'], 
  this.onSignInSuccess, this.onSignInError)
}
```

**What is wrong?**

Comment: Can you please double-check your app id first of all? If you had an error in that, FB.init might just fail. If you followed their examples properly, then I think that might be the most likely issue, or at least its worth making sure first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that the problem was due to having added the plugin and removed, I removed because the plugin did not work in the browser.

**I followed the steps:**

1. `$cordova platform remove android`
2. `$cordova platform add android`
3. `$cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-facebook4 --save --variable APP_ID="1854483668193025" --variable APP_NAME="Lojas"`

Answer (score 1):

I believe your configuration is correct. The only thing blocking the expected behaviour is due to the fact you are running your application through

```
$ cordova run browser
```

**Your application needs to be run or emulated on a device** for it to work properly. Thus, running it through

```
$ ionic cordova emulate (ios|android)
```

should do the job. Don't forget to add the platforms you are going to use with

```
$ ionic cordova platform add ios
or
$ ionic cordova platform add android
```

Good luck!